# How to configure vscode to automatically add new lines between functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

Here I have a two functions with no line between them:

```
const test = () => {
  console.log('test')
}
const test = () => {
  console.log('test')
}
```

After saving , I want it autoformat and add new line between this two functions like that:

```
const test = () => {
  console.log('test')
}
// new line
const test = () => {
  console.log('test')
}
```

Comment: Install prettier and use prettier formating on save in vscode settings

Answer (score 0):

Here is eslint rule:

```
"lines-between-class-members": ["error", "always"],
```

Comment: Could you explain, step by step, what to do with this line of code? From seeing it here for the very first time, to making it work, in practice?